# Gradle library including local jar as api dependency doesn't show up in consumer's classpath

Tags: gradle

In my gradle java library project, I have a dependency on a local jar file (the artifact is not published anywhere). The dependencies configuration looks like:

```
dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: '3rdparty', include: '*.jar')
}
```

When I publish my library to maven local, and then pull it in from another project, the symbols from the jar in the 3rdparty folder aren't available on the classpath, even though it's listed as an api dependency. Is this just a limitation of using jar files directly within library modules or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known limitation on *File Dependencies*. The Gradle documentation is clear on that

> File dependencies are not included in the published dependency descriptor for your project. However, file dependencies are included in transitive project dependencies within the same build. This means they cannot be used outside the current build, but they can be used within the same build.

The reason is simply that those dependencies are not externally resolvable by other projects in contrast to artifacts hosted in a binary repository. Read more about this topic in the [Declaring Dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:file_dependencies) userguide.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda figured as much, but I wasn't finding the correct spot in the docs on it.