# spring-boot-thin-launcher+gradle add local jar dependency

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am using spring-boot-thin-launcher to build a thinjar for my application. I am using gradle as my build tool and I have couple of local jar dependencies which are not available in maven repository which I am including in my build.gradle file as below

```
**compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')**
```

I add the below task to build my thin jar

```
task thinJarSourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
    from configurations.runtime.collect { zipTree(it) }
}
```

But when I tried to execute the `gradlew thinJar` task, I do not get any reference to the local jars in the genenerated pom/thin.properties file. These are normal java jars which is not built on maven platform, I neither cannot do a maven install on different machines for these jars. Can someone please help me out on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle library including local jar as api dependency doesn't show up in consumer's classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534753/gradle-library-including-local-jar-as-api-dependency-doesnt-show-up-in-consumer)